# What is a good search function for a Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm have been using this one but it doesn't seem to work for more than one entry  every time I do search after adding the second entry, if I try to search for the first entry it comes up with the second. What would be a fix

```
        for i in range(len(gclients)):
            record = gclients[i]
            if record["Name"].lower() == search1:
                if record["Surname"].lower() == search2:
                    recordfoundc = True


            for k,v in record.iteritems():
                resname = record["Name"]
                resSurname = record["Surname"]
                resnum = record["Phone Number"]
                resjob = record["Job"]
                resaddress = record["Address"]
                resemID = record["Employee ID"]

        if recordfoundc:
            print"You have just found",resname,resSurname,resnum,resjob, resaddress, resemID
            recordfoundc =  False

        else:
            print "Client not found"
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: move `for k,v in record.iteritems():` code inside if loop(after `recordfoundc = True` ) because when user details found then only you have to define this variables. Also use `break` statement.

Comment: Please replace `for i in range(len(gclients)): record = gclients[i]` by `for record in gclients:`, it is kind of painful to look at this ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Related to code:**

Move `for k,v in record.iteritems():` for loop code inside `if loop`(after `recordfoundc = True` ) because when Employee found then only you have to get Employee details from the `records`.

**No need of `for k,v in record.iteritems():` statement** because we directly access key and value from the record and we are not using variable `k` and `v` in the code.

Also use **break** statement.

Code will look like-:

```
recordfoundc = False
for i in range(len(gclients)):
    record = gclients[i]
    if record["Name"].lower() == search1 and record["Surname"].lower() == search2:
        recordfoundc = True
        #- Get Details of Employee.
        resname = record["Name"]
        resSurname = record["Surname"]
        resnum = record["Phone Number"]
        resjob = record["Job"]
        resaddress = record["Address"]
        resemID = record["Employee ID"]

        break

if recordfoundc:
    print"You have just found",resname,resSurname,resnum,resjob, resaddress, resemID
else:
    print "Client not found"
```

---

Python allowed to write **multiple condition** in the **if loop** with `and` and  `or` keyword.

Demo:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> if a==1 and b==2 and c==3:
...   print "In if loop"
... 
In if loop
>>>
```

---

**Break statement**

Use break statement to exit from the any while when any condition is satisfied.

In our case when Employee first name and last name is match in records then no need to check in other items of records.

**Demo:** Break `for loop` when value of `i` in `3`.

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...    print i
...    if i==3:
...       print "Break for loop."
...       break
... 
0
1
2
3
Break for loop.
```

---

How to get value from the dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> record = {"name": "test", "surname":"test2", "phone":"1234567890", "Job":"Developing"}
>>> record["name"]
'test'
>>> record["surname"]
'test2'
>>> record["Job"]
'Developing'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot, as you can tell i still need to learn a few things

Comment: @Mic: Welcome plz see again I updated answer. Free to ask question on stackoverflow and me (email- vivekbsable@gmail.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your printout happens after you've finished the for loop so your results variables are just the last ones you wrote (and these need to be only written to if the record matches, as pointed out in comments). You either need to print inside the for or add the results to a list for printing later. And/or as suggested, if you only want the first match, break from loop.